# How to handle a long request?

Tags: javascript, ajax, browser, notifications, timeout

I have an ajax request that may take a long time to return a response.

```
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'some_url',
    data: data,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    headers: {
      "Authorization": 'Token token="'+some_token+'"'
    }
  }).then(function(){
    do_something();
  });
```

If the request takes a few minutes then everything works as expected.  But if the response takes more than about 10 minutes; I get the following error:

```
jquery.js:9175 POST 'some_url' net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

But on the server, I can still see that my request is being processed.  When that process is finished, I can see that it sends a `Completed 201 Created ...` response.  But I believe since the error is encountered there is nothing listening for the response.

I would like to let the user know the process is finished.

Does any one know the 'best practice' way of handling this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: By default, your request should not [timeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/timeout). It sounds like somewhere a long timeout value is getting set. Have you attempted to explicitly set a `0` length [`timeout`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)? Or, set an arbitrarily long `timeout:` (a couple orders of magnitude beyond your 10 minutes, e.g. `60000000`)?

Comment: You might be hitting to the timeout of the browser. You might need to [set a timeout](https://mashupweb.wordpress.com/2013/06/26/you-should-always-add-timeout-to-you-ajax-call-in-jquery/) for your ajax call and retry if fails.

Comment: @Makyen I am not setting a timeout. @Redu I was afraid that would be it.  I did some research before posting here.  I saw that that the default timeout on `$.ajax` is 0 which is basically saying 'no timeout', however I did see that there are apparently browser specific timeouts.  I was wondering if there was a way around this?  Maybe I may need to do something on my server and signal my client that the process has completed.  I will edit my question a bit.

Comment: @user2517182, I was assuming that you were using the `0` default. As you mention, I also was considering it possible you were hitting some browser dependent timeout (the browser you are testing in is unspecified). The suggestion to try explicitly setting some large `timeout` was that the browser may use some default for `0`, but superseded that default if a `timeout` other than `0` is actually specified. This looks like what is happening may be browser dependent. Thus, you will need a solution that is tested and working across multiple browsers.

Comment: @user2517182, Does the server cache the response (i.e. if you retry the same request does the server have to restart completely over on the request, or can it send a response to a second request when the initial request is complete)? If the server does cache responses, then your callback should check for success/failure(timeout) and retry (perhaps multiple times, up to a maximum wall-time which you determine).

Comment: @Makyen I am not sure if my server caches responses.  I will have to find out, but this sounds like something I can try.  Thanks!

Comment: @user2517182, Have you looked at the browser's network monitor to see what that monitor says about the request? In other words, does that monitor show that the server actually sent an empty response (`ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`)? This may need to be confirmed with network monitoring software outside the browser in order to determine if it is actually an issue of the server sending a spurious empty response or the browser hitting some timeout. Actually, just testing in another browser sounds like a good idea to try to duplicate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Since Ajax is assynchonized, I like to apply a promise. From the top of my head i believe this works like follows:

```
function send_ajax(url, data, some_token) {
    var ajax = $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : url,
        data : data,
        processData : false,
        contentType : false,
        headers : {
            "Authorization" : 'Token token="' + some_token + '"'
        }
    })

    return ajax.promise();
}


send_ajax("url","data","some_token").done(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
    do_something();
});
```

The result is promised and when returns will execute the function inside done. 10 minutes does seem like an awful long time.

**edit: not the solution**
As I was pointed out the original Ajax call stays within its context. Meaning that the `then()` method will handle the returned call. My opted solution does not apply to the OP problem. 
For reference, the opted solution does handle the asynchronous hurdle when the ajax logic is placed in its own function with a returned value.

Comment: Thanks.  Isn't `$.ajax` a promise?  The process may happen quickly or it may take 10 or even 15 minutes. There is a file being uploaded.  My process depends on how big the file is.

Comment: $.ajax() does allow for a promise, but you will need to add it as part of teh functionality of the ajax request. The above code is how I apply it successfully. I started using this on jquery 1.9 I believe.

Comment: Actually, the jqXHR objects as of jQuery 1.5 implement the Promise interface.

Comment: @Daniel A bit down the same page you quoted from it says, "The jqXHR objects returned by $.ajax() as of jQuery 1.5 implement the Promise interface, giving them all the properties, methods, and behavior of a Promise (see Deferred object for more information)."  Does this mean $.ajax is a promise since it implements the Promise interface?  Or do you explicitly have to call $.ajax.promise() to get a promise?

Comment: How does this answer address the issue reported by @user2517182 in the Question (getting the `jquery.js:9175 POST 'some_url' net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` error)?

Comment: @user2517182 - That was not my quote ... The ajax method did not have the promise method as part of its native set of methods. Since 1.5 it was extended. That means that you can now use that method.

Comment: @Makyen - It is basically a long shot. The error 9175 does not result in anything specific on google and the net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE can have multiple causes. The indication from OP is the long processing time. I have never dealt with such long times, but I do know that the `promise()` can deal with delays in ajax calls.

Comment: @Daniel, Any type of callback or promise should be able to deal with arbitrary long delays from assigning the callback to the callback being executed as long as the context containing the callback is not destroyed. In normal situations, the destruction of the callback context should not happen without the context which is waiting to call the callback also being destroyed. However, this can happen in some unusual circumstances. If that was happening it would affect normal asynchronous callbacks in the same way as a promise. Thus, I don't feel this answer actually addresses the issue.

Comment: @Makyen - I see now. The ajax call of OP should work. My "solution" deals nicely with the asynchronous behavior when putting the ajax call in its own function with a returned value for re-usability, but you are right with saying that it does not add a solution to OP's problem. Thanks for pointing that out ..  Cheers!